# In algebra of random variables is $X + X \neq 2X$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-functions

In the algebra of random variables, is the following identity correct?
$$X + X \neq 2X$$

The underlying source of this questions is a mathematical text that considers a MLE estimator for mean of a Gaussian as an equation of random variables (rather than variates as is typically used in descriptive statistics).

So $$\hat{\mu} = \frac{x_{1} + x_{2} + ... + x_{n}}{n}$$ becomes $$\hat{M} = \frac{X_{1} + X_{2} + ... + X_{n}}{n}$$.

I know that samples are taken from the same distribution so effectively $$X_{1} + X_{2} + ... + X_{n} = X$$, wich leads to $$\hat{M} = \frac{X_{1} + X_{2} + ... + X_{n}}{n} = \frac{nX}{n}=X$$ which seems incorrect.

This made me think, that perhaps my assumption that $X + X = 2X$ is incorrect.

Comment: No. When X takes the value x, 2X takes the value 2x. The variable X does not take two different values simultaneously.

Comment: From your edit, if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed and independent you cannot say that $X_1+X_2$ = $2X_1$ or $X_1+X_2$ = $2X_2$.

Comment: @Paul I find the notation ($X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$) confusing and have found it confusing when reading various books (it seems the de facto standard). It almost implies that $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are comming from two completely different distributions. Why not use $X+X$ rather than $X_{1} + X_{2}$? Then, at least in my mind, there would be no ambiquity that the random variables are actually the same (even though the variates or realisations might be different). I could understand indices 1 and 2 being used if $X$ was a stochastic proc. with distribution different at t 1 and 2, but is not the case.

Comment: @A.L. Verminburger, things get confusing with your notation once we distinguish equality based on distribution or pointwise. You seem to want to use X + X to represent the distribution of sum of 2 identically distributed rv’s. Note that this is read as pointwise sum of the same X’s. $X_1 + X_2$ has both pointwise sense and distribution sense. We sum two rv’s pointwise, and we can also consider the new distribution. Yes they can come from different distributions but nothing says they can’t from the same one.

Comment: @James Yang Would you not use $x+x$ (or $x_{1} + x_{2}$) for pointwise sense?

Comment: If I truly meant "double this random variable", which is calculated pointwise, I write $X+X = 2X$. If I have two random variables like one represents height of male and the other height of female and I am interested in the sum, I write $X_1 + X_2$, even if they have same distribution. They may have same distribution, but pointwise, $X_1(\omega)$ and $X_2(\omega)$ may certainly be different. $X(\omega)$ is always the same as $X(\omega)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the random variable $X$ with the following pmf: $$\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\begin{cases}1/2&\text{for }k=1\\ 1/2&\text{for }k=0.\end{cases}$$

If $X_{1},X_{2},X$ are i.i.d., then let's compute the pmf of $Y=X_{1}+X_{2}$: $$\mathbb{P}(Y=k)=\begin{cases}1/4&\text{for }k=2\\1/2&\text{for }k=1\\ 1/4&\text{for }k=0.\end{cases}$$

On the other hand, the pmf of $Z=2X$ is given by $$\mathbb{P}(Z=k)=\begin{cases}1/2&\text{for }k=2\\ 1/2&\text{for }k=0.\end{cases}$$

So we can see that these are not the same distribution. The difference is coming about because in the case of $X_{1}+X_{2},$ $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are allowed to vary independently, where in the case of $2X,$ you are essentially forcing $X_{1}=X_{2},$ violating the independence assumption.

Comment: Interestingly, every formula in this highly upvoted answer is absurd. What can a statement such as $$\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\begin{cases}1&\text{w.p. }1/2\\ 0&\text{w.p. }1/2.\end{cases}$$ even mean?

Comment: Oh dear, you're absolutely right. I meant to write that the probability is 1/2 for each of the values $k=1$ and $k=0$, so I'll change this immediately. Thank you for your comment.